# How to load PGM (Portable Gray Map) file in openlayers?

Tags: openlayers, pgm

i want load a PGM file into openlayers 7, but i don't know how to load it.

i found there is a project on github "ol4pgm", but it‘s last update is already 8 years ago.
or may be i should convert pgm file to many points and use webgl point layer? or is there a better way to load PGM file now?

Comment: A pgm is just a bitmap, perhaps it's easier to just convert to tiff or png first?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if we convert the PGM to a picture, it will load well. But actually in our project, PGM is a robot slam map (point cloud), and we have a topology map in another layer. We want to make the two layers overlap and  have the same coordinate system, then it looks like PGM is background. So if we convert the PGM to a picture, we have to process the coordinate offset of the two layers. I think it is a little difficult.